# How do I assign an array to an element of a multidimensional array?

Tags: awk

GNU Awk 5.1.0

I'm building up an associative array using operations such as:

```
ptf["sysmodName"] = strip(a[1])
ptf["sysmodType"] = strip(a[2])
```

When I've finished building this, I'd like to assign it to an array of arrays using something like:

```
x = ptf["sysmodName"]
ptfs[x] = ptf
```

but awk complains:

```
 fatal: attempt to use array `ptf' in a scalar context
```

Is there an easy way to assign an entire array to an element of a multi-dimentional array in its entirety, or am I obliged to do it an element at a time?

Comment: Awk only permits arrays of scalars, and doesn't really support multi-dimensional arrays, as is well explained https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280877/multidimensional-arrays-in-awk#14281120

Comment: Hi @mevets.  Do I misunderstand, then, that modern implementations (GNU Awk 5.1.0 here) do properly support multi-dimensional arrays?

Comment: Yeah, that isn't awk, its gawk.   Sorta like C is to C++; most likely anything goes, and some of it might work...

Comment: Gnu awk supports multidimensional arrays but not copying them. Being fed up with `for` I've used `asort` to copy 1D arrays (yeah, makes no sense) but I doubt that it would work for copying multidimensional arrays. I've ran into this at some point. Not sure if I ever used it, though: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456315/clone-complex-array-in-awk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are obliged to do it 1 element at a time:

```
x = ptf["sysmodName"]
for (y in ptf) {
    ptfs[x][y] = ptf[y]
}
```

If `ptf[]` was a true multi-dimensional array (an array of arrays as supported by gawk) then see [How do you copy a multi-dimensional array (i.e. an array of arrays) in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62179750/how-do-you-copy-a-multi-dimensional-array-i-e-an-array-of-arrays-in-awk).