# awk PROCINFO["sorted_in"] Multidimensional array sorting problem

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, awk

```
[root@rocky ~]# cat c
a b 1
a c 4
a r 6
a t 2
b a 89
b c 76
a d 45
b z 9
[root@rocky ~]# awk '{a[$1][$2]=$3}END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc";for(i in a){for(x in a[i])print i,x,a[i][x]}}' c
a b 1
a t 2
a c 4
a r 6
a d 45
b z 9
b c 76
b a 89
[root@rocky ~]# awk '{a[$2]=$3}END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc";for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' c
b 1
t 2
r 6
z 9
d 45
c 76
a 89
```

```
[root@rocky ~]# awk '{a[$2]=$3}END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc";for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' c
a 89
c 76
d 45
z 9
r 6
t 2
b 1
[root@rocky ~]# awk '{a[$1][$2]=$3}END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc";for(i in a){for(x in a[i])print i,x,a[i][x]}}' c
a d 45
a r 6
a c 4
a t 2
a b 1
b a 89
b c 76
b z 9
```

```
[root@rocky ~]# awk --version
GNU Awk 4.2.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 3.1.6-p2, GNU MP 6.1.2)
```

There is a problem with the sorting of multidimensional arrays using `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"` or `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"`, and there is no real sorting. There is no problem with one-dimensional arrays. What is the problem? Is it because it does not support multidimensional arrays?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to tell us with the 4 awk scripts and associated output in your question. Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] with just 1 example of input and actual output, add the output you expected instead of what you got, and tell us what the problem is rather than just saying `There is a problem` but not telling us what it is.

Comment: Once you tell us what output you expect (and why) we can help you write the code to produce that output. Meantime you might be interested in [how-do-you-copy-a-multi-dimensional-array-i-e-an-array-of-arrays-in-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62179750/how-do-you-copy-a-multi-dimensional-array-i-e-an-array-of-arrays-in-awk) as it shows how to use `isarray()` which is probably relevant to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
awk '{a[$1][$2]=$3}END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc";for(i in a){for(x in a[i])print i,x,a[i][x]}}' c

a b 1
a t 2
a c 4
a r 6
a d 45
b z 9
b c 76
b a 89
```

This is not a bug, this is how it is supposed to work. Look closely, you are using a nested loop here.

```
for(i in a)
```

This is outer loop that will iterate through values `a` and `b` in 2 iterations.

```
for(x in a[i])
```

This is inner loop that will iterate through values of for `a,[$2]` first and `b,[$2]` second time.

`@val_num_asc` will sort values numerically in ascending order as per the value which is `$3`. If you look closely printed values `1,2,4,6,45` for `$1=a` are numerically sorted as per the value and so are `9,76,89` for `$1=b`.

---

If you want sorted output using `awk` then use this suggested *workaround*:

```sh
awk '{a[$1 OFS $2]=$3} END {PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"; for(x in a) print x, a[x]}' c

a b 1
a t 2
a c 4
a r 6
b z 9
a d 45
b c 76
b a 89
```

Comment: I don't think `@val_num_asc will sort values numerically in ascending order as per the value which is $3` is correct for the outermost loop. The value of `a["a"]` isn't whatever was in `$3`, it's an array with indices b,c,r,t,d, and similarly the value of `a["b"]` is also an array with indices a,c,d. So how do you compare 2 arrays to decide which one numerically should come first? I don't think you can and so I'd expect the order resulting from that outer loop to be random (hash) order just like if you didn't specify a sort order - the OP getting a then b is just coincidence.

Comment: Yes that is right Ed. What I meant by `@val_num_asc will sort values numerically in ascending order` is that it is sorting only values for  `a["a"]` separately and `a["b"]` separately.